# Kotlin channel - is there a non-suspending receive?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, channel

Apparently if we call `channel.receive()` against an empty channel, it suspends, which is exactly as documented here [in official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/channels.html). Is there a way to immediately return a `null` instead, like what `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`'s `poll()` does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we can use [tryReceive()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-receive-channel/try-receive.html):

```kotlin
channel.tryReceive().getOrNull()
```

Comment: can you please help me on [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75367786/8266651)