# Improve ConcurrentLinkedQueue to Channel Queue in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, queue, kotlin-coroutines, channel

I am building an application in which user can read BPM data in mobile. I was reading in some posts that I need to build a queue for that, it run at a time and hold next command in queue until it finish the first job. I used some piece of code from the [library](https://github.com/weliem/blessed-android-coroutines). I want to check my existing queue why is it slow? if anything which is more efficient then `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, then definitely I'll try that. I was reading some articles with [Channel](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/channels.html) is type of Queue which behaves **First In First Out**. TBH I don't know it will work. Can you guys help me on this?

This is function of [setupQueuePolling](https://github.com/vivek-modi/QueueApplication/blob/02e8b6ec631706eb9d73cd82323fab1437b8a5d4/app/src/main/java/com/example/queueapplication/QueueViewModel.kt#L200)

```
private fun setupQueuePolling() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Starting Polling")
            while (true) {
                synchronized(commandQueue) {
                    if (!commandQueue.isEmpty()) {
                        commandQueue.poll()?.let { qItem ->
                            qItem("This is input")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have added the queue command for calling this function [addItemToQueue](https://github.com/vivek-modi/QueueApplication/blob/02e8b6ec631706eb9d73cd82323fab1437b8a5d4/app/src/main/java/com/example/queueapplication/QueueViewModel.kt#L195)

```
fun addItemToQueue(item: (input: String) -> Unit) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Added Item ->> $item")
    commandQueue.add(item)
}
```

I am calling `addItemToQueue` in  [MainActivity.kt](https://github.com/vivek-modi/QueueApplication/blob/02e8b6ec631706eb9d73cd82323fab1437b8a5d4/app/src/main/java/com/example/queueapplication/MainActivity.kt#L30), [onConnectionStateChange](https://github.com/vivek-modi/QueueApplication/blob/02e8b6ec631706eb9d73cd82323fab1437b8a5d4/app/src/main/java/com/example/queueapplication/QueueViewModel.kt#L59), [onServicesDiscovered](https://github.com/vivek-modi/QueueApplication/blob/02e8b6ec631706eb9d73cd82323fab1437b8a5d4/app/src/main/java/com/example/queueapplication/QueueViewModel.kt#L79) & [onCharacteristicChanged](https://github.com/vivek-modi/QueueApplication/blob/02e8b6ec631706eb9d73cd82323fab1437b8a5d4/app/src/main/java/com/example/queueapplication/QueueViewModel.kt#L127) with [`GlobalScope`](https://github.com/vivek-modi/QueueApplication/blob/02e8b6ec631706eb9d73cd82323fab1437b8a5d4/app/src/main/java/com/example/queueapplication/QueueViewModel.kt#L47) using [onServicesDiscovered](https://github.com/vivek-modi/QueueApplication/blob/02e8b6ec631706eb9d73cd82323fab1437b8a5d4/app/src/main/java/com/example/queueapplication/QueueViewModel.kt#L79) & [startScan](https://github.com/vivek-modi/QueueApplication/blob/02e8b6ec631706eb9d73cd82323fab1437b8a5d4/app/src/main/java/com/example/queueapplication/QueueViewModel.kt#L216).

I don't understand, why my queue is so slow to response back in time. [Library](https://github.com/weliem/blessed-android-coroutines) is very fast to give response. My whole project is in [here](https://github.com/vivek-modi/QueueApplication).

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't this basically create a busy loop, consuming 100% of CPU and even worse, jumping in and out of the synchronized block repeatedly?

Comment: So how can I fix this problem @broot can you please guide me on this ?

Comment: @broot I just build a basic stuff, I don't know how to improve this stuff.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are polling and not reading items directly? I suggest to either go coroutines, so use `Channel` and `receive()` from it (without all these `synchronized`, `isEmpty()` and stuff - simple receive). Or go classic way and use `LinkedBlockingQueue` and `take()`. In the latter case you have to run this using `Dispatchers.IO.` In the first case you don't have to.

Comment: @broot thanks for great explaination. I don't have all this experiences. Can you please provide me working example. It really help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it's quite hard to say why it is slow. What I see is that `synchronized(commandQueue)` is being used while `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is already a thread-safe queue, so the `synchronized(commandQueue)` can be omitted.

Using features of Kotlin coroutines, I would use a `Flow` in this case, particularly [`MutableSharedFlow`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-shared-flow/). It is thread-safe and uses principles of queue. For example in this case it would look like the following:

```
private val commandFlow = MutableSharedFlow<(input: String) -> Unit>()

suspend fun addItemToQueue(item: (input: String) -> Unit) {
    commandFlow.emit(item1) // emitting item to commandFlow
}

private fun setupQueuePolling() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        // handle commands emitted in addItemToQueue() method.
        commandFlow.collect { item ->
            item("This is input")
        }
    }
}
```

If this doesn't improve the speed, further investigation should be made, perhaps BLE device executes commands slowly. Additional logs of each operation could be helpful.

Comment: It's giving me same speed to receive the data from the ble device.

Comment: can you help me in my project to build sample project of ble connection?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much time to dive into details. I need to deal with my own issues.